# How to fill gaps in series of strings?

Tags: r

I am facing a problem where a package retrieves taxonomic information (on species) which are not of the same length. Consequently, the function stores the output in a list which elements contains tables of 2 rows and various numbers of columns (1 row for the taxonomic rank, 1 row for the info itself):

```
taxo.spA <- data.frame(name=c("Animalia", "Arthropoda", "Chelicerata", 
                                 "Arachnida", "Acari"), 
                       rank=c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Class", 
                              "Subclass"))

taxo.spB <- data.frame(name=c("Animalia", "Chordata", "Vertebrata", 
                               "Gnathostomata", "Actinopterygii", "Perciformes", 
                               "Trachinoidei", "Ammodytidae", "Ammodytes", 
                               "Ammodytes tobianus"),
                       rank=c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", 
                              "Class", "Order", "Suborder", "Family", "Genus", 
                              "Species"))
```

I would like to end up with a table with ranks as columns and names as rows.
The main issue is that the taxonomy usually varies in terms of ranks with some taxa not being resolved down to the species level (like this Acari), or if resolved, the ranks may differ (absence of a Superclass) so you can not cbind or rbind those tables (=differing number of columns, or rows).

However, the taxonomic ranks follow a hierarchy so I have been trying to reconstruct this series of ranks (Kingdom down to Species, or subspecies).
I wonder what is the best approach to this? Is there a package/function that find match between two strings and location where to insert what is missing?

---

For instance:

```
ranks1 <- c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Class")
ranks2 <- c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Order")
```

The function would identify that Kingdom:Subphylum and Class are in common. But also that Subphylum and Class surround Superclass so that Superclass can be inserted between Subphylum and Class. Finally that Order is missing and should be right after Class, on its right side:

"Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Order"

Ultimately, the function I am writing will build a data.frame with n columns (=the longest taxonomy) and S rows (the number of taxa) and fill it with the taxonomic info I have on each taxa, in the correct column, leaving the rest as NAs.

```
desired.output <- data.frame(rbind(c("Animalia", "Arthropoda", "Chelicerata", 
                                     NA, "Arachnida", "Acari", NA), 
                                   c("Animalia", "Chordata", "Vertebrata", 
                                     "Gnathostomata", "Actinopterygii", NA, 
                                     "Perciformes")))

names(desired.output) <- c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", 
                           "Class", "Subclass", "Order")
```

I have tried to start with one of the most complete info I have and fill in the gaps comparing with other taxa. I have played with setdiff(), intersect(), %in%; and tried to find what's in common, what belongs to only one of the two strings and rebuild that but I am not sure that's the best way to go?

Any ideas? Suggestions?

N.B. I will keep the dataset as a dataframe (although for now more a matrix) as I will merge it with other datasets later on.

---

### **EDITS/ANSWER BELOW**

So, first of all, thanks for the help. I inspired myself from the answers and managed to get this to work.

The main problem was that the tables contained in the list (1) did not have the same number of rows, (2) rows could contain different info (some ranks may be skipped in a taxonomy)  making it hard to merge everything inside one single table.

However, the taxonomy has this tree-like hierarchy that I could use to find how those ranks branch together.
How I tackled the problem:

I used the organism which had the most resolved info as my reference (=the highest number of ranks), then took each list of ranks (a vector of ranks) and found the differences with this most resolved vector.
Then I search for the position of those missing ranks by looking at what ranks would come above and below them in the hierarchy and where they would match in my reference.

Four cases were possible (N.B. the highest rank is on the left, lowest on the right):

- **no match**: I can't place that rank in the taxonomy (yet)
- **2 matches**: I can place the missing info between the two matches in my
  reference
- **1 match on the left**: I can place it after the match
- **1 match on the right**: I can place it before the match

I looped over the missing ranks and grew sequentially the ranks until all possible ranks in the dataset were included in the vector: I used the function append() to sequentially add the missing rank after a specific position defined by positions of common ranks between the reference and other taxonomies.

Finally, I used this vector as my columns' names for the final table and filled the table with the taxa information (see below).
Maybe not the best but should be consistent across taxonomies.

Thanks a lot! (P.S. Feels nice when it is finally doing what it is supposed to do)

[image: Final table]

Comment: To correct my post, the list I get actually contains tibbles and not data.frames (I am not so familiar with this class of tables).

Answer (score 1):

You could first define a function that transforms your `taxo*`s into the incomplete end format.

```
myTransform <- function(x) {
  tr <- t(x[2:1])
  colnames(tr) <- make.names(tr[1, ], unique=TRUE)  # `make.names()` to get unique column names
  return(as.data.frame(t(tr[-1, ])))
}
```

Then put all `taxo*`s in to a list `l`. E.g. with `mget()` if they are loaded into the workspace.

```
l <- lapply(mget(ls(pattern="taxo")), myTransform)
```

(This is basically the same what `l <- lapply(list(taxo.spA, taxo.spB), myTransform)` does, but it's assumed that you have a whole bunch of `taxo*`s.)

It makes sense to add an `id` column to the data frames in the list.

```
l <- l <- lapply(1:length(l), function(x) cbind(id=names(l)[x], l[[x]]))
```

Now run `merge()` wrapped into `Reduce()` like so:

```
out <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., all=TRUE), l)
```

***Giving***

```
> out
        id  Kingdom     Phylum   Subphylum          Class Subclass
1 taxo.spA Animalia Arthropoda Chelicerata      Arachnida    Acari
2 taxo.spB Animalia   Chordata  Vertebrata Actinopterygii     <NA>
3 taxo.spC Animalia Arthropoda Chelicerata      Arachnida    Acari
     Superclass       Order     Suborder      Family     Genus
1          <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
2 Gnathostomata Perciformes Trachinoidei Ammodytidae Ammodytes
3          <NA>        <NA>         <NA>        <NA>      <NA>
             Species Subclass.1
1               <NA>       <NA>
2 Ammodytes tobianus       <NA>
3               <NA>  Something
1               <NA>       <NA>
2 Ammodytes tobianus       <NA>
3               <NA>  Something
```

***Additional data*** (to simulate duplicated column)

```
taxo.spC <- structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Acari", 
"Animalia", "Arachnida", "Arthropoda", "Chelicerata", "Something"
), class = "factor"), rank = structure(c(2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 
4L), .Label = c("Class", "Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subclass", "Subphylum"
), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer.
I am getting an error, but I am not sure why:
"Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column "

I thought it was because for fish, the dataset contains Superclass Gnathostomata and Superclass Pisces (so duplicated column names). I removed it but still this error.

Comment: "Error in fix.by(by.y, y) : 'by' must specify a uniquely valid column"

Comment: Perhaps could you extend your example data so that I could reproduce the error. Duplicated columns might be the cause of the error.

Comment: Is there a way to share an Rdata here? Would be easier as I have no clue what table is causing this error.

Comment: Probably that one with duplicated categories. What is your plan to do with duplicated categories as Superclass?

Comment: I've added an example for duplicated colnames and slightly adapted the code for duplicates. They will be numbered in the output. Please see edit.

Comment: Well... normally there shouldn't be duplicated categories except this Superclass Pisces.
It is a category that taxonomically doesn't exist but still is included in this database because when we see Pisces, we know it is a fish. I removed such duplicate normally...
Right now, I am trying something with append(). I'll test your edit right after.

Comment: I'm not sure what you want to achieve with `append()` since it's rather a merging problem. The implementation of an additional column makes sure that the code runs properly. Moreover it helps you to identify "problematic" data frames.

Comment: I will edit my answer. I managed to get the function to work with append.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
# add a column with the name of the taxonomy
taxo.spA$tax <- "taxo.spA"
taxo.spB$tax <- "taxo.spB"

# bind the rows together (an alternative to do.call(rbind, .) would be data.table::rbindlist())
# this would also work if you have more than two taxonomies 
result <- list(taxo.spA, taxo.spB) %>% 
  do.call(rbind, .) %>% 
  reshape2::dcast(tax ~ rank, value.var = "name") 

# choose the columns and the order you want
orderd_classes <- c("Kingdom", "Phylum", "Subphylum", "Superclass", "Class", "Subclass", "Order")
result[orderd_classes]
```

The result would be:

```
# Kingdom     Phylum   Subphylum    Superclass          Class Subclass       Order
# Animalia Arthropoda Chelicerata          <NA>      Arachnida    Acari        <NA>
# Animalia   Chordata  Vertebrata Gnathostomata Actinopterygii     <NA> Perciformes
```

Comment: Hi, I am not sure what is intended here. I get a contingency tables with taxa in one column, and the other columns  are ranks.
How would I go from there?
The other simpler solution I have is to store the taxonomic rank order in a vector (I think at most there is 25-30 ranks) and use them to select the right column to fill a table.
But I thought there could be a different solution if the rank names would change or if I would use a different taxonomy.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing the problem here, I'm not really an expert in your field of study but I know R, so can you help me understand what exactly the problem is? what is it exactly that you can not do with this approach?

Comment: I want to end up with a table that contains characters (the taxa names). Each columns would correspond to a taxonomic rank (~a level in a hierarchy) and each rows would contains the info of each of those ranks for a specific organism or group of organisms.
I retrieve the data from this database: http://www.marinespecies.org/aphia.php?p=taxdetails&id=2036
In parenthesis, you have the rank (e.g. Phylum) and associated to that the name of this specific Phylum (e.g. Annelida).
I found a solution I will post above.